# I cant install maven on MacOS

Tags: java, macos, maven

As the title says. I can't install maven on my Macbook.Here is the content of my bash_profile below:

```
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contexts/Home
M2_HOME=/Users/gongjianping/MySoftwares/apache-maven-3.5.3
export M2_HOME
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

I get this error:

```
gongjianpingdeMacBook-Pro:~ gongjianping$ mvn -v 
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly 
This environment variable is needed to run this program 
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
```

But I set up JDK successfully:

```
gongjianpingdeMacBook-Pro:~ gongjianping$ java -version
java version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10, mixed mode)
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Did you open a new terminal window/tab since you added the JAVA_HOME to bash_profile? Or run `source ~/.bash_profile` to re-read that file? You need to do one or the other.

Comment: Just google the error message you got, there are many solutions.

Comment: Remove M2_HOME. Only add the the path `/Users/gongjianping/MySoftwares/apache-maven-3.5.3/bin` in your PATH nothing else. Have you tried to call maven in that path...via `./mvn --version`? How do downloaded the correct package of Maven?

Comment: export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contexts/Home 
export M2_HOME=/Users/gongjianping/MySoftwares/apache-maven-3.5.3 
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin 
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx512m" 
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$M2 
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)